# How to declare _constraints for an OpenERP model?

Tags: constraints, odoo, openerp-7

I created a new model:

```
class rpe_mandate(orm.Model):
    _name = 'rpe.mandate'

    def _check_dates(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
            delivery_date = rec.delivery_date
            receipt_date = rec.receipt_date
            if delivery_date > receipt_date:
                return False
        return True

    _columns = {
        'delivery_date': fields.date('Delivery date'),
        'receipt_date': fields.date('Receipt date'),
    }

    _constraints = [
        (_check_dates, 'Error! Delivery date must be earlier than receipt date.', ['delivery_date', 'receipt_date',])
    ]
```

What I want is to show an error message if the receipt date is earlier than the delivery date.

But with my code, nothing is happening when I save a record, in both cases (if the receipt date is earlier than the delivery date and the other way around -- *I tried it too to check if I did it wrong* --)

Comment: here is example of _constraint might be helpful in future http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-create-constraints-in-openerp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were generating a new record for rpe_mandate, but through a many2many field. So, when you clicked on "Save" in the popup, it wasn't being stored in the database. You have to click on button "Save", but in the main form, to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
def _check_dates(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        delivery_date = rec.delivery_date
        receipt_date = rec.receipt_date
        if delivery_date > receipt_date:
            raise osv.except_osv(_("Alert !!"),_("Delivery date must be earlier than receipt date"))
    return True
```

Dont forget to  **import**

from openerp.tools.translate import _

Comment: Hi Baiju, I tried your code, with no results. Do I have to keep _constraints as I had, don't I? I have only changed the fuction, I left the rest as I had.

Comment: did you checked that your function works , when we click Save button?

Comment: I knew that the function of _constraints wasn't being called, and I have just realized why: I was generating a new record for rpe_mandate, but through a many2many field. So, when I clicked on "Save" in the popup, it wasn't being stored in the database. I had to click on button "Save", but in the main form, to see the error message. If you want, put this as a new answer and I'll check it as the right one.